# MySQL select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables t1, t2 and t3. Below are their schemas.

I need to join them and do have the condition.

```
In t1 table, objectName can be one of 4: 'ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI',  or 'JKL'.
If t1.objectName is 'ABC', I need to join t1.idObject with t2.id1. 
If t1.objectName is 'DEF', I need to join t1.idObject with with t2.id2. 
If t1.objectName is 'GHI', I need to join t1.idObject with t2.id3. 
If t1.objectName is 'JKL', I need to join t1.idObject with t3.id4.

I need to select t1.idObject, t1.objectName, t2.custName, t4.Message.
```

Also, if t1.objectName is 'DEF' or 'GHI', I want custName to be null in select result.

--

```
create table t1 (idObject int, objectName varchar(20));
create table t2 (id1 int, id2 int, id3 int, custName varchar(20));
create table t3 (id4 int, Message varchar(20));

select * from t1;
select * from t2;
select * from t3;

insert into t1 values (101, 'ABC'), (102, 'DEF'), (103, 'GHI'), (104, 'JKL'), (105, 'ABC'), (106, 'DEF'), (107, 'GHI'), (108, 'JKL');

insert into t2 values (101, 102, 103, 'Val'), (105, 106, 107, 'Mil');

insert into t3 values (104, 'Message1'), (108, 'Messgage2');
```

--

Query with explanation will be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: you can use the *Case* syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

Comment: You want to select `t4.Message`? There's no table `t4`, so I guess you mean `t3`. But you only join with `t3` when `objectName` is `JKL`, what should it be otherwise?

Comment: Any table with three different identity columns to join on represents a poor design.

Comment: I think this is an homework, given that the design is forcing to use joins and conditions agressively and that no context seems to be in place here. Maybe I'm wrong thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a UNION to combine the results of each query:

```
SELECT t1.idObject, t1.objectName, t2.custName, NULL Message
FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON (t1.idObject = t2.id1)
WHERE t1.objectName = "ABC"
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.idObject, t1.objectName, NULL custName, NULL Message
FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON (t1.idObject = t2.id2)
WHERE t1.objectName = "DEF"
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.idObject, t1.objectName, NULL custName, NULL Message
FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON (t1.idObject = t2.id3)
WHERE t1.objectName = "GHI"
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.idObject, t1.objectName, NULL custName, Message
FROM t1 join t3 ON (t1.idObject = t3.id4)
WHERE t1.objectName = "JKL"
```

You didn't mention it, but I assumed `Message` should be NULL in the ABC, DEF, GHI cases, since there's no such column in `t2`, and `custName` should be NULL in the JKL case because there's no such column in `t3`.

To order the result, you need to make the UNION a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t1.idObject, t1.objectName, t2.custName, NULL Message
    FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON (t1.idObject = t2.id1)
    WHERE t1.objectName = "ABC"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t1.idObject, t1.objectName, t2.custName, NULL Message
    FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON (t1.idObject = t2.id2)
    WHERE t1.objectName = "DEF"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t1.idObject, t1.objectName, t2.custName, NULL Message
    FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON (t1.idObject = t2.id3)
    WHERE t1.objectName = "GHI"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t1.idObject, t1.objectName, NULL custName, Message
    FROM t1 join t3 ON (t1.idObject = t3.id4)
    WHERE t1.objectName = "JKL" ) x
ORDER BY idObject, custName, Message
```

Comment: `Perform poorly` is generous, that other answer give totally stupid results.  This one, however, gets +1 from me :)

Comment: in above requirement, if i remove "Also, if t1.objectName is 'DEF' or 'GHI', I want custName to be null in select result." what would the query look like? could you please post below?

Comment: Just put `t2.custName` in those SELECT clauses, instead of `NULL custName`.

Comment: @Barmar How can I do order by in the above query? Just to use single order by...? order by idObject, objectName, custName, Message. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind SQL is that it allows you to phrase your exact requirements in SQL terms, like so, for example:

```
SELECT
 whatever you need, including
 CASE WHEN t1.objectName in ( 'DEF' , 'GHI') 
  THEN NULL
  ELSE t2.custName
 END AS custName
FROM
 t1, t2, t3
WHERE
 (t1.objectName = 'ABC' AND t1.idObject = t2.id1) 
 OR
 (t1.objectName = 'DEF' AND t1.idObject = t2.id2)
 OR
 ...
```

I hope you can extend this to all your requirements.

Comment: Whoa there!  Did you actually try this out?  Imagine the case where `t1` and `t2` join successfully, ***EVERY*** row in `t3` will now be joined to that result...   If you try this you'll see that you get insane results.

Comment: That's right. This would work OK if the problem were just to decide which column in `t2` to join with, but since the table to join with is also dependent on `objectName` it doesn't work correctly at all.

Comment: in above requirement, if i remove "Also, if t1.objectName is 'DEF' or 'GHI', I want custName to be null in select result." what would the query look like? could you please post below?